# Qual a melhor maneira de enviar meu projeto Spring Boot para o servidor?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou construindo minha primeira aplicação `Java Spring Boot`. Nessa primeira experiência, estou tendo dificuldade para usar com o Git e envia-lo para o servidor. A ideia principal seria: Eu puxo para um repositório privado, exemplo: `Bitbucket`, e no meu servidor faço, o `git` clone. Mas com isso, estou tendo vários problemas, então pensei na possibilidade de fazer .jar e envia-lo por ftp. Porém, nem isso funciona, no servidor quando faço `java -jar projeto.jar`, eu tenho os seguintes errors:

```
nenhum atributo de manifesto principal em projeto.jar
```

Eu gostaria de saber a partir de experiência de outros desenvolvedores, qual a melhor prática de exportar meu projeto Spring Boot para o servidor e como torna-lo fácil para manutenção e atualização.

Grato.

Comment: Alguma resposta te ajudou? Faltou algum detalhe?

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html), você deve adicionar o seguinte plugin no seu projeto para gerar um jar executavel.

Se usar Maven

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Se usar Gradle

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rodar a aplicação com java -jar projeto.jar realmente é uma opção bastante simples. Este erro está ocorrendo porque você não gerou o jar da maneira correta.

Para isso é necessário criar um arquivo chamado Manifest.mf com a seguinte instrução indicando a classe com o método main (**fully qualified name**) da sua aplicação:

```
Main-Class: br.com.projeto.Test
```

E depois gerar o jar passando esse arquivo:

```
jar -cfm projeto.jar Manifest.mf br.com.projeto
```

De modo a simplificar seu projeto, sugiro o uso do Maven, pois além de facilitar o gerenciamento de dependências, vai gerar o jar já configurado para rodar desta mesma forma. Como ponto de partida, recomendo o [seguinte tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias maneiras de realizar o deploy de um projeto Spring Boot, a maneira mais fácil é utilizando o ***fatjar*** gerado a partir de um **mvn clean install**.
Veja esse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yy8RxjdcTfE).

Uma outra alternativa é converter o JAR em **WAR** (clique [aqui](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)).

Agora é só escolher e aplicar a mesma no seu servidor.